# MATLAB Image Processing: Show multiple images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Trying to experiment with MATLAB image filtering.

I take the image, use `imshow(img)`, then apply a filter or some other transformation and call `imshow(img)` again.

For some reason, MATLAB seems to only display the image once, even if I call *imshow* or *imagesc* multiple times.

When I did this in Python, when I closed the image window, then the next image would appear. So I thought that until I closed the image window, code execution would halt. But that does not seem to be the case for MATLAB, as closing the image does nothing.

Anyone know why? Thank you.

Comment: Create a figure for each image like `figure,  imshow(img)`.

Comment: To expand on @Prefect 's comment, in Matlab code execution does NOT halt when plotting, so if your script/function has multiple `imshow()`/`imagesc()`/whatever it just overwrites the previous call with the new image. That's why you need to open up a new `figure` for each image that you want to show. Alternatively, you can use `subplot`s to have all images in a single figure.

Comment: @MatteoV
 and Prefect

Thank you!